# SQL Server 2008 R2 SSIS Packages not running (Execute Process Tasks) inside agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, bids, sql-agent

I have several SSIS packages that launch external programs either batch programs for things like SFTP or VB Scripts for older programs. These work perfectly in BI Development manager but once they are packaged and sent to MS Agent they appear to run fine with no errors but the system just seems to skip those tasks and they don't appear to run.

This happens both when the agent runs these as scheduled or when you manually trigger

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Are the files in the same locations?  Does the sql agent service account have access to the locations?  This sounds like permission/path issue

Comment: Doesn't appear to run? Is there a SSIS log entry for the task or not? Does it show success or failure? Is there any logging on the batch file/script side to give you any clues? There might be two reasons for this: 1. The Agent service account doesn't have access to the scripts 2. You're incorrectly referring to a drive letter that doesn't exist